# Apache Airflow on Kubernetes with DAGs from local registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow

I'm new to Airflow and I'm trying to set it up locally on Kubernetes using the official [helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) with kind. It's pretty straight-forward up to the point where I want to configure Airflow to load DAGs from an image in my local Docker registry.

I created my image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.3.0
COPY .dags/ ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/
```

I created a local Docker registry running on port 5001 (the default 5000 is occupied by macOS):

```
reg_name='registry'
reg_port='5001'
cluster_name='airflow-cluster'
running="$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' "${reg_name}" 2>/dev/null || true)"
if [ "${running}" != 'true' ]; then
  docker run \
    -d --restart=always -p "${reg_port}:5000" --name "${reg_name}" \
    registry:2.7
fi
```

I then pushed the image to the local registry without issues.

I used the following config to create the kind cluster (kind-cluster.yaml):

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
containerdConfigPatches:
  - |-
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."127.0.0.1:5001"]
      endpoint = ["http://127.0.0.1:5001"]
nodes:
- role: control-plane
```

I created the cluster like so:

```
kind create cluster --name "${cluster_name}" --config kind-cluster.yaml
```

Then connected the registry to the cluster network:

```
docker network connect "kind" "${reg_name}"
```

I also did this, although I'm not sure whether this was necessary (found it on the Internet when debugging the network issue...):

```
for node in $(kind get nodes --name=${cluster_name}); do
  kubectl annotate node "${node}" "kind.x-k8s.io/registry=127.0.0.1:5001" --context "kind-${cluster_name}" ;
done
```

I used values.yaml from the official helm chart with just a minor change in the images section:

```
# Images
images:
  airflow:
    repository: 127.0.0.1:5001/my-dags
    tag: 0.0.1
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

The problem I have however is that there seems to be no network connectivity between the kind container and my local host. Helm deployment does not finish and when I run `kubectl describe pod` I see the following errors:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  50m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/apache-airflow-run-airflow-migrations-bbfd8 to airflow-cluster-control-plane
  Normal   Pulling    49m (x4 over 50m)     kubelet            Pulling image "127.0.0.1:5001/my-dags:0.0.1"
  Warning  Failed     49m (x4 over 50m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "127.0.0.1:5001/my-dags:0.0.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "127.0.0.1:5001/my-dags:0.0.1": failed to resolve reference "127.0.0.1:5001/my-dags:0.0.1": failed to do request: Head "http://127.0.0.1:5001/v2/my-dags/manifests/0.0.1": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5001: **connect: connection refused**
  Warning  Failed     49m (x4 over 50m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     49m (x6 over 50m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m15s (x89 over 50m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "127.0.0.1:5001/my-dags:0.0.1"
```

Of course if I curl http://127.0.0.1:5001/v2/my-dags/manifests/0.0.1 from my local machine it works without issues.

What else do I have to do to make Airflow read DAGs from an image in my local Docker registry? Or maybe I don't need this local registry at all to have Airflow read DAGs from a container image?

Comment: You are probably not still puzzling over this but you need to publish that docker image to your network. Then in values.yaml, rather than using localhost you would use your container name. This youtube video may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjBADrVQJv0&list=PL79i7SgJCJ9hu5GqcA091h6zuewmsvSyy&index=22

Comment: Indeed I already moved on but thanks for your input! Hopefully it will be useful for someone else. What I did eventually was to just use docker-compose - somehow it was easier for me and everything worked fine.